# Java JDBC UPDATE Add Number?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So let's say I have an `int` column in MySQL. I want to update that column by adding to it, without running a `SELECT` query to get the number and add it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 update tablename set field = field + 1 where condition
```

This is a direct MySql update command to do so.  You didn't mention if you were using a specific ORM like Hibernate or anything, but this same concept can be applied in HQL etc.